# In Ant colony optimization , can anyone explain what are the values to be entered in the formula?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

The below TSP example is discussed in most of the ppt's
The distance between the nodes :

A---100->B

B--60--->C

D---150-->E

In 1st iteration , the ant is in A moved to D  : A-->D

```
                                             B-->C
                                             C-->B
                                             D-->E
                                             E-->A
```

In 2nd iteration , the ant is in AD moved to C

```
                             BC moved to D
                             CB moved to E
                             DE moved to A
                             EA moved to B
```

In 3rd iteration , the ant is in ADC moved to E

```
                             BCD moved to A
                             CBE moved to D
                             DEA moved to B
                             EAB moved to C
```

In 4th iteration , the ant is in ADCE moved to B
                                 BCDA moved to E
                                 CBED moved to A
                                 DEAB moved to C
                                 EABC moved to D

[A,D,C,E,B]   L1=300

[B,C,D,A,E]   L2=450

[C,B,E,D,A]  L3=260

[D,E,A,B,C]  L4=280

[E,A,B,C,D]   L5 =420

Here my doubt is how to compute L1,L3 ,L3,L4 values using ant colony approach?